# How can I validate the queue message?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Currently I have this code:

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmq.queue}")
public void receivedMessage(TransferPayment transferPayment) {
  log.info("Received message: {}", transferPayment);

  // TODO: please correct
  if (transferPayment.getData().getSecurity() != null &&
    transferPayment.getData().getNotification() != null &&
    transferPayment.getData().getTransfer() != null &&
    transferPayment.getData().getDisbursementDestination() != null &&
    transferPayment.getData().getDisbursementDestination().getThirpartyDestination() != null &&
    transferPayment.getData().getCustomer() != null &&
    transferPayment.getData().getCustomer().getIdentification() != null &&
    transferPayment.getData().getLoans() != null) {

    notificationUseCase.notifyPayment(transferPayment);
  }
}
```

[image: Message of Queue]

I want to improve the conditional and be able to perform the same validation correctly in a cleaner way. Keep in mind that due to SonarLint issues I can't use more than 5 logical operators in the conditional, I also want to correct that.
I am using clean architecture and this code is in the infrastructure layer and object `TransferPayment` is in the domain layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a validator to the message handler factory and annotate the parameter with `@Valid`; this externalizes the validation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#async-annotation-driven-enable-signature

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#rabbit-validation

> SonarLint issues I can't use more than 5 logical operators

You can reduce the condition count by storing intermediate results in local booleans and then check that all are true.